# CSS not working fine in IE9 but it works fine in all other versions

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

i am using jquery addRule but it is not working fine in IE9 how i can resolve this issue. any help please

check this code

```
var ss=document.createStyleSheet();
ss.insertRule("v\\:shape", "behavior:url(#default#VML);")
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery does not have an `.addRule()` method. Only >IE9 supports [the `addRule` method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuucnct.php).

You should be using [`insertRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Stylesheet.insertRule) instead.

**Edit**: In fact, you should check for both as IE8 and below do not support `insertRule`:

```
if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
  // all except IE < 9
} else if (stylesheet.addRule) {
  // IE < 9
}
```

Assuming `stylesheet` is your stylesheet object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it shows error like this Microsoft JScript runtime error: DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)

Comment: My mistake, `elseif` should be `else if`.